# django celerybeat not invoking tasks.py function

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celerybeat

Based on the tutorial: https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-celery-beat/

**celery.py file code**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from Backend.settings import INSTALLED_APPS

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**tasks.py file code**

```
from celery.task import task
@task(name='task1')
def emailt():
    print("email func invoked")
    # code...
```

**settings.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import djcelery
from celery.schedules import crontab
djcelery.setup_loader()

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'djcelery',
'django_celery_beat',
 ....
]

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'   

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'task1': 
    {
        'task': 'proj.tasks.emailt',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='*', minute='1', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun'),
    }
}
```

In one command shell, redis server and django py manage.py runserver is running.
On another shell, the celery command is run as follows: celery -A proj.tasks beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler

**Log files denote that celerybeat is running.**

```
Configuration ->
. broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
. loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
. scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

. logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
. maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
[*************: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[*************: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[*************: INFO/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
[*************: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[*************: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
```

However, the function emailt() within tasks.py is still not getting invoked.
I am unable to locate the issue with celerybeat.

Comment: I am not sure, but you set `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER` to be `djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler`, so it uses `djcelery` as scheduler. Have you tried removing this line?

Comment: @Tirzono it does not as you can clearly see running config in log
. scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DatabaseScheduler](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) is the database scheduler implementation and doesn't take tasks from `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` dictionary

If you are going to use this type of scheduler you should create [PeriodicTask](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-creating-interval-based-periodic-task) through django admin or through data migrations/views

You can use crontab notation with default scheduler in tasks or with DatabaseScheduler by creating [CrontabSchedule](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-creating-crontab-based-periodic-task) and attaching it to [PeriodicTask](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-creating-interval-based-periodic-task)

Comment: for the PeriodicTask and CronTabSchedule objects, should they be created in the settings.py file ? (so that the method within tasks.py file can be automatically detected)

Comment: Or do these objects need to be created in the celery.py file?